# how do I compare a string of integers with an integer?

Tags: python, string, list

I have written the code below:

```
d = 4
int_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
string_digits = [str(int) for int in int_list]
str_of_ints = ''.join(string_digits)

this produces -> str_of_ints = 1491625 (and this is a string)

for i in str_of_ints: 
    if i == 'd': 
        print("hello")
```

the issue I have is with the line i == 'd' ; this is returning false- why is this? And how can I compare the string 1491625 with say an integer 5, in particular how can I check if any of the digits of 1491625 is equal to 5?

I have tried doing:

```
for i in str_of_ints: 
    if i == d: 
        print("hello")
```

this of course doesn't work because then we would be comparing a string with an integer?

Comment: `if i == str(d):` or `if int(i) == d:`

Comment: It's not clear why you're converting to a string, rather than leaving them as integers, since the latter would really simplify the script.

Comment: You can also get rid of the loop and just use `if str(d) in str_of_ints:`

Comment: You want `d = '4'`. you need to use the string `'4'` not the string `'d'`, `'d'` does not convert the object being referenced by the variable `d` into a string.

Comment: Please don't use `int` as a variable name.

Comment: Also, it doesn't produce a "string of ints", it *produces a string*.

Comment: @RandomDavis The result would be different if there are any 2-digit numbers in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is comparing an integer `d` to a string as you iterate over `str_of_ints`. Your data types must match. 4 is not the same as '4'. This can be solved by converting your searched value to a str using the `str()` method:

```
d = 4
int_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
string_digits = [str(int) for int in int_list]
str_of_ints = ''.join(string_digits)

# this produces -> str_of_ints = 1491625 (and this is a string)

if str(d) in str_of_ints:
    print('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
d = 4
int_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
str_list = [str(i) for i in int_list]
str_string = "".join(str_list)
if str(d) in str_string:
    print("hello")
```